# Clear selected record in List grid smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I have a list grid which displaying records retrieve from Rest data source. When I reset the list grid it clear all records from list grid. But already selected record remains same. My need is, the selected record should not remain selected after reset. I have tried invalidatecache, redraw, setData. But nothing works.Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this method should work.

```
listGrid.deselectRecord(record);
```

So you could do something like this:

```
listGrid.deselectRecord(listGrid.getSelectedRecord());
```

Or if that doesn't work you could try selecting the first record in the grid with:

```
listGrid.selectRecord(0);
```

Comment: Great! If I helped you, could you accept my answer?